# Is it possible to highlight a substring of text inside of a tableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that I can search through using a search bar.

I would like to either hi-light or bold portions of text that match the string passed into the search bar.

For example, if the tableview contains: "Apple" and "Orange" and I type the letter "a", I would like the cells to now contain "**A**pple" and "Or**a**nge"

Through much googling I have not found a way to modify substrings of text within a table view title property.

Anyone have any idea if this is even possible?

Something like this is what I am trying to achieve in a table view:

[image: Something like this is what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486761/make-part-of-a-uilabel-bold-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
func attributedText(withString string: String, boldString: String, font: UIFont) -> NSAttributedString {
  let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string,
                                             attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])
  let boldFontAttribute: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: font.pointSize)]
  let range = (string as NSString).range(of: boldString)
  attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: range)
  return attributedString
}
```

Pass the total string and the search string in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and assign return `attributedString` to you label

It may helps you. Thank you.