# Using attributed text programmatically in label inside cell

Tags: swift

Currently I have the following text inside a label located in a cell:

```
var textvalue: String? = nil

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            textvalue = "Person: \(`pow`.name)"
            break
        case 2:
            textvalue = "Place: \(`pow`.address)"
            break
        default:
            fatalError("Error")
        }

    cell.textLabel?.text = textvalue

        return cell
    }
```

How can only the text `Person:` and `Place:` be bolded? Instead of the entire text string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make part of a UILabel bold in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486761/make-part-of-a-uilabel-bold-in-swift)

Comment: Well in my case there are different kinds of bold text string, I just don’t understand how this can implemented for a case like mine

Comment: @KennethPans You need to have attributed string and then simply udpate label like -- label.attributed  = "your attributedStr"

Comment: @KennethPans have a look at the answers on the link, you can create a function and just pass your text and return an attributed text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like below:

```
    var textvalue: String?

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
       cell.textLabel?.attributedText =
       NSMutableAttributedString()
           .bold("Person: ")
           .normal(`pow`.name)
       break
    case 2:
       cell.textLabel?.attributedText =
       NSMutableAttributedString()
           .bold("Place: ")
           .normal(`pow`.address)
       break
    default:
       fatalError("Error")
    }

    return cell
}
```